# PHP Error with INSERT SQL

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have an error with my PHP CODE, the error is:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\modding-gaming.com\check_register.php on line 91

And I don't understand it ..

My PHP CODE: ( i'm french )

```
                   <?php
include('includes/connect_db.php');
    if (isset($_POST['create']))
    {
        if  ((isset($_POST['nom'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['nom'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['prenom'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['prenom'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['pseudo'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['pseudo'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['age'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['age'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['email'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['email'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['about'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['about'])) &&
            (isset($_POST['mdp'])) && 
            (!empty($_POST['mdp'])) &&      
            (isset($_POST['mdp_ok'])) &&
            (!empty($_POST['mdp_ok'])))
        {
            extract($_POST);
            if (strlen($_POST['pseudo']) < 4 || strlen($_POST['pseudo'] > 15))
                {
                    echo 'Le pseudo doit contenit 4 à 15 caracteres.';
                    exit();
                }        
            else {
                    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE pseudo = ?');
                    $req->execute(array($_POST['pseudo'])) or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));

            $compte_pseudo = $req->rowCount();

            if ($compte_pseudo > 0)
                {
                   echo 'Le pseudo est deja utilise.';
                   exit();
                } 
        }
    if ($age< 10) 
        {
            echo 'Vous devez avoir 10ans ou plus pour pouvoir vous inscrire.';
        } else if ($age >= 100)
            {
                echo 'Veuillez rentrer un age correct.';
                exit();
            } else {

                    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?');
                    $req->execute(array($email));

                    $compte_email = $req->rowCount();

                    if ($compte_email > 0)
                    {
                        echo 'L\'email est deja utilisee.';
                        exit();
                    } 

            if ($sexe != 'Homme' && $sexe != 'Femme')
            {
               echo 'Veuillez definir votre sexe.';
               exit();
           }

                if (strlen($_POST['mdp']) < 5 || strlen($_POST['mdp_ok'] > 20))
                {
                    echo 'Le mot de passe doit contenir 5 a 20 caracteres.';
                } else if (!($_POST['mdp'] == $_POST['mdp_ok'])) 
                    {
                        echo 'Les mots de passe doivent etre identique.';
                    } else 
                        {
                        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                        $date_creation =  date("d/m/Y",time());
                        $hash_mdp = sha1($mdp);
                        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(pseudo, password, sexe, prenom, nom, age, email, grade, about, ip, created) 
                                            VALUES(:pseudo, :mdp, :sexe, :prenom, :nom, :age, :email, :grade, :about, :ip, :date_creation)') or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
                        $req->execute(array(
                            'pseudo' => $pseudo,
                            'password' => $hash_mdp,
                            'sexe' => $sexe,
                            'prenom' => $prenom,
                            'nom' => $nom,
                            'age' => $age,
                            'email' => $email,
                            'grade' => 'Administrateur',
                            'about' => $about,
                            'ip' => $ip,
                            'created' => $date_creation
                             )) or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
                        }
            }          

} else 
    {
       echo 'Veuillez remplir tous les champs.';
    }
```

} // End

Thank's you !

LINE 91:

```
 )) or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
```

Comment: can you show us line 91 in your code?

Comment: Your query has `:mdp` but you are binding `password`

Comment: You're missing the `mdp` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Add **`:`** colon before the array params that you are sending. Do like this..

```
$req->execute(array(
                            ':pseudo' => $pseudo,
                            ':password' => $hash_mdp,   <----- Should be :mdp instead of :password
                            ':sexe' => $sexe,
                          ---^
```

Do that for all keys.

Comment: Although it's not documented, PDO allows you to leave out the colons here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(pseudo, password, sexe, prenom, nom, age, email, grade, about, ip, created) 
                    VALUES(:pseudo, :mdp, :sexe, :prenom, :nom, :age, :email, :grade, :about, :ip, :date_creation)') or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
                    $req->execute(array(
                        ':pseudo' => $pseudo,
                        ':mdp' => $hash_mdp,
                        ':sexe' => $sexe,
                        ':prenom' => $prenom,
                        ':nom' => $nom,
                        ':age' => $age,
                        ':email' => $email,
                        ':grade' => 'Administrateur',
                        ':about' => $about,
                        ':ip' => $ip,
                        ':date_creation' => $date_creation
                         )) or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
                    }
```

Comment: You were using password and created instead of mdp and date_creation